# "oeuvre": foreign phonemes in a loanword

Tags: phonology, phonemes

I recently came across *oeuvre*, which in the two out of two times I've heard the word spoken (in an English context), sounded like it does in [Merriam-Webster's online audio pronunciation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oeuvre), that is, with a vowel that does not occur in any other English word, loanword or otherwise. (As a side note, [various](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oeuvre#English) [other](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oeuvre) [dictionaries](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=oeuvre&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=R2FuT_nrEO7ksQKd_riOBg&ved=0CCkQkQ4&biw=1920&bih=1016) seem to list some very peculiar pronunciations, together with hilariously pronounced audio samples that do not match the transcriptions.) On the other hand, a quick check [here](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opus%2Coeuvre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests that the word has really been around in English long enough to have gotten more Anglicized. Are there any other English words with /œ/, or other non-English phonemes? What would have to happen to qualify /œ/ as an English phoneme? Is there a name for the use of phonemes that are not part of a language?

Comment: The part of your question about English specifically would be best answered on English.SE I think. The more general question about linguistic borrowing of phonemes would be a good topic here though. Perhaps you could edit your question to focus on that last bit?

Comment: well i know that _hors d'oeuvre_ has been pretty well nativized.

Comment: @jlovegren yes, and notably for the question, it's not pronounced [œ] in English unless one is hypercorrecting.

Comment: the same people who have the occasion to pronounce _oeuvre_ probably also know how to pronounce _coup d'oeil_ and _trompe l'oeil_. Interestingly, English has acquired the foreign phoneme [gb], in the dialect spoken by newscasters reporting on affairs involving former Ivoirien president Laurent Gbagbo.

Comment: @jlovegren Interesting, are they truly using a coarticulated labial/velar or a [g][b] sequence? And if the latter, can we say that they've acquired a *phoneme*?

Comment: What about the /x/ phoneme for words of Celtic origin like _loch_. Some speakers of English do pronounce it with the /x/ and some with a /k/ so that _loch_ and _lock_ are homophones. Also in the British Isles placenames like _Llanelli_ has /ɬ/ and this phoneme does remain for some speakers of English when pronouncing these words.

Comment: Apparently the French r is still too hard to make it into English :P

Answer (score 6):

A good question, but I'm afraid there's no good answer to it.

The phenomenon has been noticed by linguists some time ago, and we have two terms: ***loan words*** and ***foreign words***. For the latter also the German term is sometimes used, *Fremdwort* (pl. *Fremdwörter*) -- incidentally, itself a good example of its own meaning. There is at least one more like that in English, namely *menu*. I don't know why it hasn't been adapted better. Maybe because it's a 'vocabulary word', maybe because there aren't many more like it, and maybe both.

But the second possibility is key here: the feeling of nativeness of a phoneme/word/anything is a function of its **frequency**. English native speakers don't perceive [œ] as native because it's only there in very few (possily just one) words, and not a very frequent one to that. As it is, it's a foreign word. If there were many more like it, they would become loan words.

Two examples:

1. Polish originally did not have /f/. When the Latin name *Stephanus* was borrowed, it was adapted to *Szczepan* [ščepan]. But later many other words with /f/ have been borrowed and Poles began to perceive it as a native sound. The connection between *Stephanus* and *Szczepan* became obscure, and the name was borrowed again, yielding *Stefan* [stefan] this time. (Both exist in modern Polish and are seen as two separate names.)
2. Turkish originally did not have either /f/ or /ž/. Since the 10th century, however, it has borrowed a large number of words with /f/ but only relatively few with /ž/. As a result, the former is now seen as a native sound much more than the latter.

So you can see that the distinction is a **gradient** and comes down eventually to the **proportion**. Unfortunately, no scale or mathematical formula seems to exist which would allow to specify the feeling.

The process is not limited to phonemes. I wrote "phoneme/word/anything" above. It's because this is how we perceive familiarity in general. In the 19th c., English purists attempted to convince the society to abandon French, Latin &c. loan words and thus 'purify' the language. The slogan they came up with was *Use exclusively Anglo-Saxon monosyllables*. In case you wondered, *use* is a borrowing from French.

Comment: Another example: English [ʒ] was in origin a borrowing from Norman French, although it's now thoroughly nativized.